# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Replace with Selection.Find.Execute() more then the first word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I try to make a Report in C# with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. I have a template and some different words which i want to replace. But if i use

```
> Selection.Find.Execute()
```

it replace only the first word.
My Code:

```
 Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
            Word.Document doc = null;

            object template = "ReportTest.dotx";
            object toFile = "ReportFinish.doc";

            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            doc = app.Documents.Open(template, missing, missing);
            app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
            app.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

            app.Selection.Find.Execute("[organisation]", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                missing, "Firedepartment");
            app.Selection.Find.Execute("[trainer]", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                missing, "John Silver");

            app.Selection.Find.Execute("[trainee]", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                missing, "Smith");

            object Save = (object) toFile;
            doc.SaveAs(Save,missing,missing,missing);

            doc.Close(false,missing,missing);
            app.Quit(false,false,false);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

So if it founds organisation it replaced it with Firedepartment but the other one didnt change. So is there a way to replace all different words ?

The word-template looks like:

```
Department: [organisation] 
Trainer: [trainer] 
Trainee: [trainee]`
```

The finish document should look like:
Department: Firedepartment
Trainer: John Silver
Trainee: Smith

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for using `Selection.Find` says

```
 When the item is found that matches the search criteria, it is automatically selected.
```

I would add a call to

```
app.Selection.Collapse();
```

just before the second and third calls to `Find.Execute`.

Comment: OMG! Thanks! This helped me